# Install new gitlab and have variable error

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I run a new Gitlab and get an error:

> There was an error fetching the variables

when going to `Admin Area > CI/CD`.

I test different docker image versions (gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.0.0-ce.0 and latest version) but it not fix my problem:

[image]

[image]